# Mysql CASE and UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this query which updates only the first column that is empty. Here is a query so far:

```
UPDATE `names` SET 
`name_1` = CASE WHEN `name_1` = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_1` end,
`name_2` = CASE WHEN `name_1` != '' and `name_2` = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_2` end
```

It updates all of columns with 'Jimmy'. I think that that's because the SET will update it then move on to the next SET and will update that etc...Am I right on what's causing this? If so how could I fix this? If not how should I rewrite this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: *It updates all of columns with 'Jimmy'.* umm it didn't for me when I tried it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c24b/1). Perhaps you should create a SQL Fiddle of your own to demostrate it

Comment: Alright will do, give me a minute.

Comment: Actually I see it happened on your link too. On the first row they're are both empty before you update them but after you run the update it sets both them to 'Jimmy'. I wanted it to only set one of those empty spots to 'Jimmy'.

Comment: Either way here is a replica of my DB with the query I'm trying to do. [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a71c7/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you swap the order, it will work properly.

Try this:

```
UPDATE `names` SET 
`name_2` = CASE WHEN `name_1` != '' and `name_2` = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_2` end,
`name_1` = CASE WHEN `name_1` = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_1` end
```

Comment: *Slow clap* My god, such a obvious problem I over looked. Thank you very much! Here is your upvote and checkmark :)

Comment: No problem.  The best solution is usually the simplest one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if null values might be causing you problems.  You could use the IFNULL function to convert them to empty strings (in case you have empty strings and NULLs).  Try this:

```
UPDATE `names` SET 
    `name_1` = CASE WHEN IFNULL(`name_1`, '') = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_1` end,
    `name_2` = CASE WHEN IFNULL(`name_1`, '') != '' and IFNULL(`name_2`, '') = '' then 'Jimmy' else `name_2` end
```

or if you have all nulls:

```
UPDATE `names` SET 
    `name_1` = CASE WHEN `name_1` IS NULL then 'Jimmy' else `name_1` end,
    `name_2` = CASE WHEN `name_1` IS NOT NULL and `name_2` IS NULL then 'Jimmy' else `name_2` end
```

Comment: I thought of that too but I changed my DB structure to not use null. Here is replica of my DB http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a71c7/1/0

Comment: Try to swap two sets, I think the second set is affected by first set.